# Laravel : api throttling (rate ) is this mandatory for spa?

Tags: laravel, api, single-page-application, rate-limiting

I need to have clarification about laravel throttle.
I couldn't find how does this work in details.

My api is used for a front end app as spa.
But sometimes when a lot of users refresh the page at the same time they all receive 429 error (they refresh the page only once).

Is this a trouble with session_driver or it consider my front end app as one user and apply throttle for all request that come from my font app idk ?
I don't understand how does this work, i thought it was "scope" by user ...

To solve the 429 issue i commented the throttle middleware in my kernel,
is that a good move ? or there is a bug with my throttle and it souldn't behave like that.

```php
        'api' => [
            // 'throttle:100,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

(i'm on laravel 6, this project will be destroyed in one month but i still need the answer thx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe commenting the throttle is not a good practice, instead of that, i suggest you to increase it's value to something like this:
`throttle:800|maxAttempts,1`